# How do I know the state of the ToggleButton from another activity?

Tags: java, android

How do I know the state of the ToggleButton from another activity?

i have class

```
public class MainScreen extends Activity{   
    protected ToggleButton tgbutton;    
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.mainscreen);           
       tgbutton = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.advice); 
       SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
               .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
       tgbutton.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("toggleButton", false)); 
    }        
    public void oneClick(View v) { 
        if(tgbutton.isChecked() == false) { playSound(mSound); }
        else { pauseSound(mSound); }  
        }
    }
```

and

```
public class SmallprintA extends Activity {     
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
       setContentView(R.layout.smallprint_a);
    OnClickListener SendOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {           
            if(tgbutton.isChecked() == true){ playSound(mEmpty); }
            else { playSound(mEmpty); }
            }
        };  
}
```

I need in the class SmallprintA determine the state of the ToggleButton tgbutton. This is possible without class inheritance?

Comment: Show some related part of code

Comment: for another class? did you mean from another activity? btw, you can store the state in sharedPreferences

Comment: @P.Dm: send Toggle state using intent in SmallprintA Activity from MainScreen

Comment: was enough to make a "static ToogleButton tgbuton". thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I did tgbutton is static

```
   public class MainScreen extends Activity{   
            protected static ToggleButton tgbutton;    // STATIC
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.mainscreen);           
               tgbutton = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.advice);                    
            }        
            public void oneClick(View v) { 
                if(tgbutton.isChecked() == false) { playSound(mSound); }
                else { pauseSound(mSound); }  
                }
            }
```

and

```
public class SmallprintA extends Activity {     
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
       setContentView(R.layout.smallprint_a);
    OnClickListener SendOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {           
            if(MainScreen.tgbutton.isChecked() == true){ playSound(mEmpty); }
            else { playSound(mEmpty); }
            }
        };  
}
```